# iOS custom button can't detect touch up on time

Tags: swift

I am new to iOS dev, in android for one minute I make custom button with two images normal and hover. I don't know in iOS swift how to do that, few days I am trying, I try but I can't catch touch so I can switch images for non click and click state. If I do that with button there are some delays for touch up and it's not good. I also try with imageView but it's doesn't work. Any help with this?

Comment: Check out the `setImage(_:for:)` method of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set different images for the button states (for highlighted state and normal state)

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "normal-img"), for: .normal)

button.setImage(UIImage(named: "dark-img"), for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: I do that but on my simulator and iphone 7 device when I click on button than up, it takes about 1 second until image is back to normal I want almost after up to set image to normal, it looks unresponsive in this way...

Comment: You can also try with `button.setBackgroundImage:for:`  for unresponsive UI

Comment: Okey, in other way around, did you mean Button should hover/highlight  for one minute !!?

Comment: it's better but still there is delay when up which in my opinion is not good :)

Comment: btn.isSelected = !btn.isSelected this is key for delay that I had :)

Comment: no, my need is hover only while touch down, about highlight that's ok to have delay